# How to prepare JSON for batch update

Tags: ruby

I am using Ruby 1.9.3 without Rails and am trying to prepare email addresses for sending to an email service providers API. I have to break up the sends into batches. I'm using 3 here as an example. First, I get the referrals that we will send from a database query.

```
referrals = @db.query("SELECT * FROM referrals")
```

I am taking then taking referrals and using each_slice to create the batches. However, when I run the following code the log entry for prepared_batch has no content while the log entry for referral['client_email'] contains the correct values.

```
referrals.each_slice(3) do |batch|
  prepared_batch = batch.map do |referral|
    { 
      :EMAIL => referral['client_email'], 
      :EMAIL_TYPE => 'html' 
    }
    @log.info("referral in prepared_batch: #{referral['client_email']}")
    @log.info("prepared_batch : #{prepared_batch}")
  end
end
```

What should I update here so that prepared_batch has the correct three entries?

I appreciate all advice. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are actually putting the result of a `@log.info` call in the prepared batch. Try this:

```
referrals.each_slice(3) do |batch|
  prepared_batch = batch.map do |referral|
    @log.info("referral in prepared_batch: #{referral['client_email']}")
    { 
      :EMAIL => referral['client_email'], 
      :EMAIL_TYPE => 'html' 
    }
  end
  @log.info("prepared_batch : #{prepared_batch}")
end
```

Answer (score 1):

`prepared_batch` is assigned only *after* the `map do .. end` is done. I believe that's why you didn't get a value *in* the block.